# Multicast not reaching application layer - Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, python, windows-10, multicast

I have a python application that receives multicast packets from one of the ethernet ports set to a static ip on a windows machine.  The other ethernet port is a usb-eth dongle configured for another network (dhcp).

When running, wireshark shows the multicast packets arriving on the eth port I expect, however these packets never get all the way up to python.

I swapped the ethernet ports (both cables and settings) so that the static network now receives multicast on the dongle, and now the python application is successfully getting the packets.  However, after a reboot cycle the problem has resurfaced and switching the ethernet ports hasn't solved it again.

My knowledge of routing in windows is pretty limited...  I have two questions:
1) What could be going on here?
2) How can I 'pin down' the ethernet port that is supposed to get the multicast so my setup is stable?

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution but I have almost the exact same issue.  Streaming multicast video through a USB to Ethernet adapter.  Worked one time and now, nothing.  Did you get a pop up from Window Defender Firewall by chance?  I did, told it to allow and it stopped working.   I was able to stream through the internal Ethernet port and still can.  This is unacceptable because I have to disconnect from my network to stream video.   I would look at your Windows Defender Firewall setting.  Maybe set a rule to allow Python to receive multicast video.